# Dealing with Spring Security configuration when testing controllers with @WebMvcTest

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test

We our using Spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE and JUnit 5 in our web project. We have implemented Spring security using JWT tokens. Currently, I am trying to unit test one of the secured resource as shown below

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = ItemCategoryRestServiceImpl.class)
class ItemCategoryRestServiceImplTest {

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  ItemCategory itemCategory;

  @Test
  void testFindById() throws Exception {
    ItemCategoryEntity itemCategoryEntity = new ItemCategoryEntity("Shoes");
    itemCategoryEntity.setId(15L);
when(itemCategory.findItemCategoryById(15L)).thenReturn(itemCategoryEntity);
    this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/find/id/15"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value("15"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("Shoes"));
}

}
```

When I run this test I get error for missing `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint` which is a custom bean extending `AuthenticationEntryPoint`.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig'.
>
> No qualifying bean of type 'com.some.store.common.security.jwt.config.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Intuitively, I am inclined towards disabling security configuration for testing non-security use cases to have more isolation for tests. I have tried disabling the security using `@WebMvcTest(value = ItemCategoryRestServiceImpl.class, secure = false)` but that has already been deprecated and will probably be removed in coming releases. I have come across posts about new Spring security test framework due to which it is being deprecated and advocate to use features like `@WithMockUser`. That might be a good case for integration testing in a staging environment but I am still not convinced to use it for unit tests.

For that reason I want know:

1. What will be right approach to test our unit tests when `@WebMvcTest` auto configures Spring security.
2. Secondly, by removing `secure` flag are we being forced to use Spring security test library.
3. If I want to go with my original approach of completely disabling Spring security in @WebMvcTest. Is there still a way to do it other than `secure` flag?

Comment: So you are geting errors in code that you have not posted and want us to help?

Comment: I posted the relevant part. Let me know what exactly you are interested in?

Comment: no you did not post the relevant parts. If that was the relevant part would you have solved it? You should post as much of your codebase as possible, or a reproducible example. Where is the code for `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint` where is your entire security configuration? This is not reproducible at all